# Calculus 2 question

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $y = x^2$
Estimate the distance along this curve from $x = 0$ to $x = 2$ using
straight line distances on the intervals $[0, 1]$ and $[1, 2]$.
Is this question asking me to calculate approximating area?

Comment: No, it's asking you to approximate distance, not area.  My guess is that this is a lead-in to arc length.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE. You're being asked to approximate [arc length](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx), not area. The length of those two segments will be an approximation for the actual arclength of $y = x^2$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$.

Visually, you're using the two black segments $AB$ and $BC$ as a stand-in for the green parabola between $A$ and $C$.

[image]